# How to select an Item from asp:Dropdownlist on Page load from Code Behind C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, drop-down-menu, listitem

I tried so many articles around, like below to get my task done, but didn't work as I always ends up with an **NullReferenceException**, I have bound a database table column to the Dropdown list, on page load i want to select an item based on the value from database which is one of those listed items. Please help me.

```
txt_examtype.DataSource = dt;//txt_examtype is the dropdownlist
                txt_examtype.DataTextField = "ExamTypeName";
                txt_examtype.DataValueField = "ExamTypeName";
                txt_examtype.DataBind();


String examtype = dt.Rows[0]["ExamType"].ToString().Trim();
                ListItem myitem = txt_examtype.Items.FindByValue(examtype);
                txt_examtype.SelectedValue = myitem.Value;
```

Comment: On which line do you get the exception?

Comment: I assume `myitem` is null, so there is no ListItem with a value of `examtype`. Maybe you have to use `Items.FindByText(examtype);`. Use the debugger, what items does the dropdown contain? Maybe you need to specify a different column for `DataTextField` and/or `DataValueField`. Its the same column.

Comment: Now in this case the value of examtype was "MCQ" so myitem coudn't be null right? and I had no idea on why use both DataTextField and DataValueField, Just wanted to bind the values of the column "ExamTypeName" to this dropdownlist, please correct me!

Comment: If the item is not there, finding by text or by value would be the same. I would suggest to use `if(myitem != null) txt_examtype.SelectedValue = myitem.Value;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code

```
 txt_examtype.SelectedValue =  dt.Rows[0]["ExamType"].ToString()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set SelectedIndex instead of SelectedValue. This is safe to use:

```
txt_examtype.SelectedIndex = txt_examtype.Items.IndexOf(txt_examtype.Items.FindByValue(examtype));
```

Comment: This never gave me an exception, but it did not selected the value when the page loads, but thanks afzalulh

Comment: afzalulh, this method worked for me whenever the list items are static, and not loaded from the database.